# setting up lualatex paths with local texlive

Tags: luatex, texlive, installing

I have two installations of texlive: the one provided by my distro (gentoo linux) and the "full" texlive distribution installed to a subdirectory of `/home/[user]/`.

I'm working on a project that depends on finding custom `.sty` files within its own paths, and depending on whether I use the system lualatex or my local one, I get conflicting results, and neither of which compiles successfully.

In the two code examples below, [ROOT] refers to the root subdirectory of the project infrastructure and [user] refers to the subdirectory of `/home/[user]/` where I have the "full" texlive installed locally. The switch `--target=cantatas.three` is locally defined by the project and refers to a specific subgroup of the project to be compiled. `kaysermake.cls` is the project's locally defined class file, and can be found by `kpsewhich` (see below).

Using "local" texlive:

```
[ROOT] $ ~/tex-local/texlive/2017/bin/x86_64-linux/lualatex --shell-escape make.tex --target=cantatas.three
This is LuaTeX, Version 1.07.0 (TeX Live 2018) 
 system commands enabled.
(./make.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-04-01> patch level 4
(using write cache: ~/.texlive2018/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic)(
using read cache: ~/carrier1/tex-local/texlive/2017/texmf-var/luate
x-cache/generic ~/.texlive2018/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic)
luaotfload | main : initialization completed in 0.100 seconds

! LaTeX Error: File `kaysermake.cls' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: cls)

Enter file name: x
```

Using system texlive:

```
 [ROOT] $ lualatex --shell-escape make.tex --target=cantatas.three
This is LuaTeX, Version 1.0.4 (TeX Live 2017) 
 system commands enabled.
(./make.tex
LaTeX2e <2017/01/01> patch level 3
(using write cache: ~/.texlive/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic)(usin
g read cache: //var/lib/texmf/luatex-cache/generic ~/.texlive/texmf
-var/luatex-cache/generic)sh: all: command not found

luaotfload | main : initialization completed in 0.110 seconds
Babel <3.10> and hyphenation patterns for 1 language(s) loaded.
[SNIP, but it did find kaysermake.cls]
)) (/usr/share/texmf-site/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgffor.code.tex
(/usr/share/texmf-site/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex)))sh: all: command not found
~/texmf/tex/luatex/latex/kaysermake.lua:56: module '/config/luaconfig.lua' not foun
d:
    no field package.preload['/config/luaconfig.lua']
    [kpse lua searcher] file not found: '/config/luaconfig.lua'
    [kpse C searcher] file not found: '/config/luaconfig.lua'
    no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.2//config/luaconfig.so'
    no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.2/loadall.so'
    no file './/config/luaconfig.so'
stack traceback:
    [C]: in function 'require'
    ~/texmf/tex/luatex/latex/kaysermake.lua:56: in main chunk
    [C]: in function 'require'
    [\directlua]:1: in main chunk.
l.16 ...ectlua{ kayser = require("kaysermake.lua") }

? x
```

searching for `kaysermake.cls` with kpsewhich:

```
[ROOT] $ kpsewhich -debug=32 kaysermake.cls
[SNIP]
kdebug:search([kaysermake.cls]) => 
~/texmf/tex/luatex/latex/kaysermake.cls
~/texmf/tex/luatex/latex/kaysermake.cls
```

So, what can I do here to make sure that the "full" texlive installation can find the local `.cls` files? Is there a `.cnf` file I should edit? What is the syntax for adding entries to a `.cnf` file?

Thanks for the help!

**Addendum**: I have used the following test file "lualatex-tester.tex":

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\directlua{
p = io.popen('/usr/bin/git --version')
result = p:read('*a')
print()
print(result)
p:close()
}
\end{document}
```

and the command '[ROOT] $ ~/tex-local/texlive/2017/bin/x86_64-linux/lualatex --shell-escape lualatex-tester.tex', to get the following output:

```
$ ~/carrier1/tex-local/texlive/2017/bin/x86_64-linux/lualatex --shell-escape lualatex-tester.tex
This is LuaTeX, Version 1.07.0 (TeX Live 2018) 
 system commands enabled.
(./lualatex-tester.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-04-01> patch level 4
(using write cache: ~/.texlive2018/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic)(
using read cache: ~/carrier1/tex-local/texlive/2017/texmf-var/luate
x-cache/generic ~/.texlive2018/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic)
luaotfload | main : initialization completed in 0.099 seconds
(~/carrier1/tex-local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/articl
e.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class

(~/carrier1/tex-local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10
.clo(save: ~/.texlive2018/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/fonts/otl/
lmroman10-regular.lua)(save: ~/.texlive2018/texmf-var/luatex-cache/
generic/fonts/otl/lmroman10-regular.luc))) (./lualatex-tester.aux)
git version 2.17.0


(./lualatex-tester.aux))
 362 words of node memory still in use:
   2 hlist, 1 vlist, 1 rule, 2 glue, 4 attribute, 45 glue_spec, 4 attribute_lis
t, 2 write nodes
   avail lists: 2:7,3:1,4:1,5:4,7:1,8:1,9:1

warning  (pdf backend): no pages of output.
Transcript written on lualatex-tester.log.
```

However, if I replace "/usr/bin/git" with just "git" in the popen statement, the same command fails with the "sh: all: command not found" error posted above.

According to my colleague, this shows some odd behavior, in that it seems unable to find git unless I specify the absolute path.

What might be going wrong here?

Comment: As it is a texlive 2018 `tlmgr conf auxtree add path/to/local/texmf`  should normally work. See the documentation of tlmgr.

Comment: would that path, in my case, be ~/carrier1/tex-local/texlive/2017/? Or some other path?

Comment: `~/texmf/`  as this is the texmf-tree with your local class. Perhaps you need to replace ~ by its extension.

Comment: This returned: 
`$ ~/carrier1/tex-local/texlive/2017/bin/x86_64-linux/tlmgr conf auxtree add ~/texmf/
tlmgr: unknown conf arg: auxtree (try tlmgr or texmf or updmap or auxtrees)
tlmgr: An error has occurred. See above messages. Exiting.
`
except I wrote out the ~ part.

Comment: you want to adjust the texlive 2018 so why on earth do you use the texlive 2017 tlmgr?  Also the error message tells you to try `auxtrees` with an s at the end.

Comment: when I used `tlmgr --gui` and updated, it updated to the 2018 version without changing the name of the directory. That tlmgr returns `tlmgr revision 47303 (2018-04-05 19:52:22 +0200)` when `tlmgr --version` is run. In any case, now running with `auxtrees` updated, and now I'm a bit further along in compilation. The error I now get is something I have to discuss with my colleague, as I think it's something wrong with my lylualatex installation, which is separate from this issue.